# not seeing my output from my nodejs Lambda.. only basic baseline response data

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a lambda that I can see is pushings logs to cloudwatch, it is in test mode still..

```
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    console.log("TESTING 123");
    
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify('Hello from Lambda!'),
    };
    
    console.log(response)
    
    return context.logStreamName;
};
```

I was expecting to get to iterate in here with the logs and kind of confirm things that way.. but when I goto the logs they do not have my console output.

```
2022-07-13T17:22:54.170Z
UUID123
2022/07/13/[$LATEST]UUID123
1.19
2
@billedDuration
2.0
@duration
1.19
@ingestionTime
UUID123
@log
UUID123:/aws/lambda/my-test-lambda
@logStream
2022/07/13/[$LATEST]UUID123
@maxMemoryUsed
5.8E7
@memorySize
1.28E8
@message
REPORT RequestId: some-id-123 Duration: 1.19 ms Billed Duration: 2 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 58 MB
@requestId
UUID123
@timestamp
123
@type
REPORT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the behavior I observed was.. I had all the right permissions.. I had logs of the `START` and `END` coming through.. I even tried wiping the lambda and starting over with good permissions incase it was the loggroup created by myself manually..

in the end what jump started my logs was hitting `Deploy` in the GUI once... After that first deploy suddenly all my logs started to pop up in the cloudwatch and monitoring sections.. very strange but.. well now I know and hopefully save someone else from scratching their heads.

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas about what you could check (sorry if you've already checked):

1. Check that your Lambda has permissions to write logs on CloudWatch (it should have permissions for `logs:CreateLogGroup`, `logs:CreateLogStream` and `logs:PutLogEvents` which are the allowed actions for the `AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole` role) (visible on the **Configuration > Permissions > Resource summary** tab).
2. Check that you have `START` and `END` messages (with the same `RequestId` as the one in the `REPORT` message you've pasted), and that you have no logs between those (logging to `stdout` through `console.log` makes usually your logs appear between those).

Comment: for some reason I just hit deploy and everything started logging... I guess in the test area you will not get your output without deploying at least once?